# Interact.js draggable elements prematurely "dropped" in chrome and android emulator

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, interact.js, interactjs

I'm updating an old Ionic + Angular app, and am seeing a strange behaviour: elements made `draggable` with Interact.js will drag for a few hundred milliseconds, only to abort prematurely and fire the `dragend` event. The strange part is that the behaviour is only visible when testing the app in an android device, and in chrome via `ionic serve`. *Firefox via `ionic serve` works fine!*

I've tried to isolate this as much as I can, running exactly the example from the [docs](https://interactjs.io/docs/draggable/) within a component in my Ionic 7 + Angular 17 + Capacitor 6 app:

package.json:

```
    "@interactjs/types": "^1.10.26",
    "interactjs": "^1.10.26",
```

component:

```
import interact from 'interactjs';

...

const position = { x: 0, y: 0 }

interact('#test-draggable').draggable({
  listeners: {
    start (event) {
      console.log(event.type, event.target)
    },
    move (event) {
      position.x += event.dx
      position.y += event.dy

      event.target.style.transform =
        `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`
    },
  }
})
```

...to no avail! can anyone else reproduce this? it's like all you can do is nudge elements a few pixels. i'm at a point where i don't know what i'm missing, and i really don't want to rewrite this thing using a different dragging library. perhaps something about angular change detection?

thanks in advance everyone! take good care.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378072/2343242) worked for me. How s/he found this i have no idea lol.

Add this css to the parent element within which you are dragging things around:

```
.parent-container {
    touch-action: none;
}
```